# Django. How can I add a widget for image input

Tags: python, django

How can I add a widget for image input.

Here  code in file 'forms.py' in Django project

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ['name', 'img']
    widgets = {
        'name': TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Name'
        })
    }
```

Code in HTML:

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.name }}<br>
     {{ form.img }}
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">submit</button>
    <span>{{ error }}</span>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change your `form` in `template`.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```